# how to design a search panel like in mashable with css only

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to build a search panel like in the mashable site
http://mashable.com/
so when the user is hovering on the search icon a search panel will be open.
Initially I thought to build this with a css pure approach with something like that

```
<ul>
    <li> menu item 1</li>
    <li> menu item 2</li>
    <li> menu item 3</li>
    <li id="serach">
        search
      <ul>
        <li>
           <input type="text placeholder="search">
           <input type="submit" value="search">
        </li>
     </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

the css section

```
<style>
    li#serach ul{
     display:none;
   }
   li#serach:hover >ul{
   display:block;

  }
</style>
```

a working example can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/mBTQX/
The problem is that when the user is hovering to the left inside the menu the search bar is disappearing (because the hover effect is only done on the search li). I want that the search panel will remain even if the user is hovering on the menu nav itself exactly like it is implemented in http://mashable.com/

Can anyone advise me how I can do it and if it is possible to do it with pure css or an extra js code is needed

Comment: Why is jQuery in your tags if you want a pure css solution?

Comment: How to achieve world domination with only three minions? I guess noone is going to do it for me, just like noone is going to write your code for you !

Comment: Right now it's hard to work with your jsFiddle because of the large amount of extra HTML and CSS that's not relevant to your problem.  I'd suggest paring it down a bit to just what's relevant; then it would be easier for people to answer.

Comment: I've tested this on IE10 and Chrome and it's working. Try to clear up the code, leaving only the relevant parts and be more specific on what is the expected behavior and what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks i did some clean up and put only the relevant code. the example  is working - but when user is hovering outside the search li the search panel is disappears, i need the the search panel will remain if the user is hovering on the rest of the navigation green panel
like in mashable site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Using some jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/fZgS9/3/

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    var nav = $('#nav');
    var search = nav.find('li.search');

    search.on('mouseover', function(event) {

        search.children().addClass('show');

    });

    nav.on('mouseleave', function(event) {

        search.children().removeClass('show');

    });

});
```

This is the basic idea (without js):

http://jsfiddle.net/fZgS9/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="search">
        <div>
            <input type="text"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: #09A065;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#nav > li.search {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

#nav > li.search > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: none;
}

#nav > li.search:hover > div {
    display: block;
}

#nav > li.search:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2000em;
    height: 1em;
    background: red;
    content: "";
}
```

The key is to play with position relative/absolute and display none/block, and the li:hover affects the inner div using child selector.

> I want that the search panel will remain even if the user is hovering
>   on the menu nav itself...

Tricky, but done using a pseudo element, you can hide it with opacity, but it will cover the rest of the menu... hummm... use JS...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to do this with Javascript.  That said, it's not impossible to achieve the effect you're looking for with CSS.

If your problem is that, when hovering over parts of the menu that aren't `li#search` but also aren't another menu item, the dropdown search box disappears, you can fix it by making `li#search` wider.  Of course, this might cause trouble if you have a hover effect for all `li` that you don't want to cover a wider area.  The solution to his new problem is to override the `li:hover` styling for `li#search`, and apply it instead to a `div` within `li#search`:

So your **HTML** could be something like this:

```
<li id="search">
    <div>Search</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text placeholder="search">
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And your **CSS** could be something like this:

```
li:hover, li#search:hover div {background-color:blue;}
li#search {width:50px;padding-left:50px;}
li#search:hover {background-color:none;}
li#search div {width:50px;}
li#search > ul {width:100px;}
```

You can adjust these styles to match your own site (I would have done so, but the jsFiddle you posted has too much CSS to weed through).  The important thing is that the effective width (width + padding) of `li#search` matches the width of `li#search > ul`.